# Why do people declare array size sometimes?

Tags: c

Why there is a need to declare array size for example: type "array[50]" while type "array[]" will still do the same thing. And I have seen other similar things in some code

Comment: *"array[]" will still do the same thing* - in general it won't - only when you have explicit initialisers for the entire array will this be the case. (Assuming you're talking about variable definitions, and not prototypes, function parameters, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Talking about arrays in function parameters

In function parameters, it's true that `int array[]` and `int array[40]` are *exactly* the same thing (they both are transformed by the compiler to `int *`); however, I've seen the second form being used as a form of documentation for output arrays, to show to client code at least how big the array is expected to be.

Personally, I'm kind of ambivalent about this use, since it *is* useful for documentation, but novices often think that (1) this requirement is somehow enforced by the compiler and (2) that `sizeof(array)` works as expected.

### Talking about array definitions

First of all, you can do `int array[]` only if you are initializing it with something, e.g. in

```
int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

the compiler is doing you a favor by counting the elements in the initializer and making the array big enough; but you cannot just do:

```
int array[]; /* does not compile */
```

because the compiler wouldn't know how big an array to allocate.

Now, sometimes people do:

```
int array[50] = {1, 2, 3};
```

This is can be useful because you have a default value for the first values, and the other are initialized to zero. This is often done with strings:

```
char buf[256] = "test";
```

Here you have `buf` initialized with `"test"`, but you still have headroom for other characters, which is often used if you e.g. want to concatenate other strings to it or use the full size of the buffer in different code paths.

```
char username[256] = "guest";
if(requireLogin) {
    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    if(!fgets(username, sizeof username, stdin)) exit(1);
    size_t sz = strlen(username);
    sz && username[sz-1]=='\n' && username[sz-1]=0;
}
logCurrentUser(username);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to supply the array size explicitly if the compiler cannot work it out from the number of initialisers passed, if any.

For example `int array[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};` is equivalent, and preferable, to `int array[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};` If you want to have more elements in the array than there are initialisers, then you should specify the size.

If you don't specify any initialisers, then you *must* supply the size.